# javascript select td´s and count duplicates

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

You can see following the code where I am trying to select the third `td` out of a table to count the duplicates.

I want save them in a new array and use the new array to iterating and find the duplicates.

I tried following to select the wanted `td`. Firefox gives me all items in the `td` where `<sport>` tag is in but IE shows me just one sport tag. Note the code is after the table

```
function doIt()
{   

var table = document.getElementById('table');
var tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
content = new Array;

for (var i=0; i<tr.length; i++)
{
content = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[2].innerHTML;
document.write(content);
}
}

<tr class="grey">
  <td><Date>25.09.2014</Date></td>
  <td><Time>09:00:00</Time></td>
  <td><Sport>Soccer, Tennis</Sport></td>
</tr>
<tr class="blue">
  <td><Date>25.09.2014</Date></td>
  <td><Time>09:45:00</Time></td>
  <td><Sport>Basketball, Volleyball</Sport></td>
</tr>
<tr class="grey">
  <td><Date>25.09.2014</Date></td>
  <td><Time>10:00:00</Time></td>
  <td><Sport>Soccer, Tennis</Sport></td>
</tr>...
```

Comment: `content = new Array();` or `content = []`. `and content[i] = ...`. your code is full of errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood what you wanted. Here's a JS that works. It looks through all the `sport` tags and only adds the ones that are not. **[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LeC2Q/)**.

```
// Initialize empty array    
var array = [];

// Get all the sport tags
var sportTags = document.getElementsByTagName('sport');

// Iterate over the sport tags
for(var i = 0; i < sportTags.length; i++){
    // Get the inner HTML
    var current = sportTags[i].innerHTML;

    // If it does not already exist, add it to the array
    if (array.indexOf(current) < 0) {
        array.push(current);
    }
}

// Print the array to check the results
alert(array);
```

Comment: thank you. im a programming beginner.. im sry my thinking was the wrong way